# Index of last whitespace in each item of a character vector

Tags: r, vector, sapply

I have got a character vector `x` as

```
 [1] "Mt. Everest" "Cho oyu" "Mont Blanc" "Ojos del Salado"
```

And I am looking for an output giving me the index of last white-space

```
[1] 4 4 5 9
```

I believe I need to use sapply so that my function applies to each item in the vector, however unable to write that:

```
sapply(x,myFunction)
```

For `myFunction` I write something like:

```
myFunction <- function(a){
match(a,c(" "))
}
```

which understandably gives all `NA` as no item is a space only.

I dont want to use `stringr` for this.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `mapply` is to split the characters on whitespace,  calculate the number of characters of last element and subtract it from the total characters of the string.

```
myFunction <- function(a){
  mapply(function(p, q) q - nchar(p[length(p)]), strsplit(a, "\\s+"), nchar(a))
}  

myFunction(x)
#[1] 4 4 5 9
```

**How it works :**

Let's take the last element from the list :

```
x <- "Ojos del Salado"

#Split on whitespace
p = strsplit(x, "\\s+")[[1]]
p
#[1] "Ojos"   "del"    "Salado"

#Select the last element 
p[length(p)]
#[1] "Salado"

#Count the number of characters in the last element
nchar(p[length(p)])
#[1] 6

#Subtract it from total characters in x
nchar(x) - nchar(p[length(p)])
#[1] 9
```

**data**

```
x <- c("Mt. Everest", "Cho oyu" ,"Mont Blanc", "Ojos del Salado")
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak , works well, can you please explain me the logic inside mapply?

Comment: @Deep Updated the answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`regexpr` will do...

```
v <- c("Mt. Everest", "Cho oyu", "Mont Blanc", "Ojos del Salado")

#find position of space, not followed by a space until the end of string    
regexpr(" [^ ]*$", v)

#int [1:4] 4 4 5 9
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame( v = v ) %>% mutate( lastspace = regexpr(" [^ ]*$", v) )

#                 v lastspace
# 1     Mt. Everest         4
# 2         Cho oyu         4
# 3      Mont Blanc         5
# 4 Ojos del Salado         9
```

Comment: regexpr gives:  [1] 4 4 5 9
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 8 4 6 7
attr(,"index.type")
[1] "chars"
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE

Comment: @Deep that's correct... a integer vector with a couple of attributes... Have you read the helpfile? `regexpr returns an integer vector of the same length as text giving the starting position of the first match or -1 if there is none`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `gregexpr`

```
x = c("Mt. Everest", "Cho oyu", "Mont Blanc", "Ojos del Salado")

lapply(gregexpr(pattern=" ", x), max)
```

If you would like your answer as a vector

```
> sapply(gregexpr(pattern=" ", x), max)
[1] 4 4 5 9
```

Credit: Answer was improved with help of @markus

Comment: @markus : Yes, your solution is better. Thank you. I will edit to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

---

Using `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)
myFunction <- function(a){
  str_locate(a, " (?=[^ ]*$)")[, 1]
}

myFunction(x)
# [1] 4 4 5 9
```

---

Using `stringi` (and avoiding regex):

```
library(stringi)
myFunction2 <- function(a){
  stri_locate_last_fixed(a, " ")[, 1]
}

myFunction2(x)
# [1] 4 4 5 9
```

---

Using `strsplit()` from base R (and avoiding regex also):

```
myFunction3 <- function(a){
  sapply(strsplit(x, ""), function(x) max(which(x == " ")))
}

myFunction3(x)
# [1] 4 4 5 9
```

---

Data:

```
x <- c("Mt. Everest", "Cho oyu", "Mont Blanc", "Ojos del Salado")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `grepRaw()`:

```
sapply(x, function(x) max(grepRaw(" ", x, all = TRUE)))

Mt. Everest         Cho oyu      Mont Blanc Ojos del Salado 
          4               4               5               9
```

With `dplyr`:

```
data.frame(x) %>%
 mutate(res = sapply(x, function(x) max(grepRaw(" ", x, all = TRUE))))

                x res
1     Mt. Everest   4
2         Cho oyu   4
3      Mont Blanc   5
4 Ojos del Salado   9
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and concise alternative

```
sapply(a,function(x){last(which(strsplit(x,"")[[1]]==" "))})

    Mt. Everest         Cho oyu      Mont Blanc Ojos del Salado 
              4               4               5               9
```